# Creating an aspectJ library using sbt-aspect

Tags: scala, sbt, aspectj, aspect, sbt-aspectj

I am in the process of writing a library that does monitoring/OpenTracing and I am attempting to use sbt-aspectj so that users of the library don't need to manually instrument their code. I am currently however getting an issue with creating an sbt-project representing such a library.

The idea is that I want an external library as indicated in this sample here https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/tree/master/src/sbt-test/weave/external however that external library is dependant on an external dependency (i.e. `akka-actors`). Basically I am trying to combine both https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/tree/master/src/sbt-test/weave/external and https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/tree/master/src/sbt-test/weave/jar. I have created a sample project here https://github.com/mdedetrich/sbt-aspectj-issue to indicate the problem I am having however below is the relevant sample

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(SbtAspectj)
  .settings(
    name := RootName,
    version := Version,
    // add akka-actor as an aspectj input (find it in the update report)
//    aspectjInputs in Aspectj ++= update.value.matching(
//      moduleFilter(organization = "com.typesafe.akka", name = "akka-actor*")),
    // replace the original akka-actor jar with the instrumented classes in runtime
//    fullClasspath in Runtime := aspectjUseInstrumentedClasses(Runtime).value,
    // only compile the aspects (no weaving)
    aspectjCompileOnly in Aspectj := true,
    // ignore warnings (we don't have the target classes at this point)
    aspectjLintProperties in Aspectj += "invalidAbsoluteTypeName = ignore",
    // replace regular products with compiled aspects
    products in Compile ++= (products in Aspectj).value,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion
    )
  )

lazy val test = (project in file("test"))
  .enablePlugins(SbtAspectj)
  .settings(
    aspectjBinaries in Aspectj ++= update.value.matching(
      moduleFilter(organization = Organization, name = s"$RootName*")),
    aspectjInputs in Aspectj ++= update.value.matching(
      moduleFilter(organization = "com.typesafe.akka", name = "akka-actor*")),
    fullClasspath in Runtime := aspectjUseInstrumentedClasses(Runtime).value,
    // weave this project's classes
    aspectjInputs in Aspectj += (aspectjCompiledClasses in Aspectj).value,
    products in Compile := (products in Aspectj).value,
    products in Runtime := (products in Compile).value,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      Organization %% RootName % Version
    )
  )
```

The idea is that we publish the `root` project using `root/publishLocal` and the test project is just designed to include `root` as a `libraryDependency` so we can see if the aspect-j is working properly.

The problem is simple that I am unable to get it working. The current code at https://github.com/mdedetrich/sbt-aspectj-issue publishes with `root/publishLocal` (not sure if its correct though) however when I then do `test/run` I get this

```
[info] Weaving 2 inputs with 1 AspectJ binary to /home/mdedetrich/github/sbt-aspectj-issue/test/target/scala-2.13/aspectj/classes...
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last test / Compile / packageBin for the full output
[error] (test / Compile / packageBin) java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 29, 2019 4:31:27 PM
sbt:sbt-aspectj-issue>
```

Which seems to be an issue with having duplicate `akka-actor` entries. I tried toggling various entries in `build.sbt` but didn't manage to get it working.

EDIT: This was also posted as a github issue here https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can exclude the `META-INF` directories from the external libraries woven.

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) := {
    (mappings in (Compile, packageBin)).value
        .filterNot(_._2.startsWith("META-INF/"))
}
```

But for akka libraries, there is another problem. In each akka library, there is a `reference.conf`, which contains the fallback configuration for the provided  features. This will also lead to conflicts like the `META-INF` did. But it cannot be just excluded like the `META-INF`, because they are essential for akka to work properly.

If you exclude them, you'll have to provide all the required akka configurations in your `application.conf`, or a merged (not simply concatenate) `reference.conf` in your project. It's not trivial, and subject to version change of akka.

Another solution would be weaving and repackaging the akka libraries individually, so the `reference.conf` can be kept in the repackaged libraries. The project layout and build script will a bit more complicated, but also be easier to maintain if you have plan to upgrade to newer versions of akka in the future.

Comment: This sounds like a workaround rather than a solution to the original issue.

`Another solution would be weaving and repackaging the akka libraries individually, so the reference.conf can be kept in the repackaged libraries. The project layout and build script will a bit more complicated, but also be easier to maintain if you have plan to upgrade to newer versions of akka in the future.`

Can you provide an example of this? Do you mean you just have a project that only contains AspectJ classes? I am also curious how projects like kamon (which also use AspectJ weaving) solve this problem